# MapView custom onTouch never called after zoom controls

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview, ontouchlistener

I have set an OnTouch listener on a mapView that show a toast. Everything works great but if  i put this code

```
map.displayZoomControls(true);
map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

then the onTouch is never called.